# Is there a web page that will let me paste ugly URL and convert it into nice - change %3A into :

Tags: url

Here is my ugly URL:
http://feedsifter.com/?f=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.rozhlas.cz%2Fnews%2Fpodcast.rss&23%3A00%2Cplus

The nice webpage should allow me to paste the ugly URL and get this as output:

http://feedsifter.com/?f=http://static.rozhlas.cz/news/podcast.rss&23:00,plus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decode URL entities on [this simple](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) javascript implementation of URL decoder/encoder.

Just put your URL in textarea and click decode.